# Algorithm: identify pairwise conflicts in a set of objects, given only "there is a conflict in this list" oracle

Tags: algorithm

I have an (unordered) set of objects.  I also have an oracle, which takes an *ordered list* of objects and returns true if there was at least one *ordered conflict* within that list, false otherwise.  An ordered conflict is an ordered pair of objects (A,B) such that the oracle returns true for any input list [..., A, ..., B, ...]. (A,B) being an ordered conflict does not necessarily imply that (B,A) is an ordered conflict.

I want to identify all *unordered* conflicts within the set: that is, find all pairs {x, y} such that *either* (x, y) or (y, x) is an ordered conflict as defined above.  The oracle is  slow (tens to hundreds of milliseconds per invocation) so it is essential to minimize the number of oracle invocations; the obvious naive algorithm (feed every possible ordered pair of set elements to the oracle; O(n²) invocations) is unacceptable.  There are hundreds of set elements, and there are expected to be fewer than ten conflicts overall.

This is as far as I've gotten: If the oracle returns true for a two-element list, then obviously the elements in the list constitute a conflict. If the oracle returns false for *any* list, then there are no *ordered* conflicts in that list; if the oracle returns false for both list L and the reversal of list L, then there are no *unordered* conflicts in L.  So a divide-and-conquer algorithm not entirely unlike the below ought to work:

```
Put all the set elements in a list L (choose any convenient order).
Invoke the oracle on L.
  If the oracle returns false, invoke the oracle on rev(L).
    If the oracle again returns false, there are no unordered conflicts within L.

# At this point the oracle has returned true for either L or rev(L).
If L is a two-element list, the elements of L constitute an unordered conflict.

Otherwise, somehow divide the set in half and recurse on each
```

I'm stuck on the "divide the set in half and recurse" part.  There are two complications.  First, it is not sufficient to take the top half and then the bottom half of the ordered list, because the conflict(s) might be eliminated by the split (consider [...A1, A2, ... An ...][...B1, B2, ...Bn ...]).  Enumerating all subsets of size n/2 should work, but I don't know how to do that efficiently.  Second, a naive recursion may repeat a great deal of work due to implicit state on the call stack -- suppose we have identified that A conflicts with B, then any oracle invocation with a list containing both A and B is wasted, but we still need to rule out other conflicts {A, x} and {B, x}.  I can maintain a memo matrix such that M[a][b] is true if and only if (A, B) has already been tested, but I don't know how to make that play nice with the recursion.

Additional complications due to the context: If any object appears more than once in the list, the second and subsequent instances are ignored.  Furthermore, some objects have *dependencies*: if (P,Q) is a dependency, then any oracle input in which Q appears before the first appearance of P (if any) will *spuriously* report a conflict.  All dependencies have already been identified before this algorithm starts.  If P conflicts with A, it is not possible to know whether Q also conflicts with A, but this is an acceptable limitation.

(Context: This is for identifying pairs of C system headers which cannot be included in the same source file.  The "oracle" is the compiler.)

Comment: base case: `a,b` are an unordered conflict if there's a conflict in `a,b,a`

Comment: I'm interested in the background story (what you need it for).

Comment: @JanDvorak Edited into question.  Also, because of that, your base case doesn't work: `a,b,a` is functionally equivalent to `a,b`.

Comment: Hm... interesting. Are you sure the oracle isn't faster when there are fewer headers?

Comment: how come the conflicts are ordered? What kind of conflict is that? Includes?

Comment: @JanDvorak For instance, on NetBSD 6 do `printf '#include <net/if.h>\n#include <rpcsvc/rstat.h>\n' | cc -fsyntax-only -xc -`.  Then repeat with the headers in the opposite order.  Then have a look at the preprocessor output if you'd like to make your head explode.

Comment: @JanDvorak The oracle (compiler) does run faster when there are fewer headers in the input, but it also has large fixed startup costs.  It is, for instance, *enormously* faster to invoke it twice on a list of 200 headers than 40,000 times on lists of two headers each.

Comment: My guess is that you should not recurse into two half lists, but (first) reverse half of the list + rinse + repeat. looks a bit like FFT - butterfly tables. And eliminating the conflict free segments ASAP seems to be the way to go.

Comment: concerning the new limitation - is it just that dependenies may ocasionally reorder the list as perceived by the compiler, or is there some other kind of false conflict? Are we given the list of dependencies?

Comment: I feel like statistically trying to reduce the Shannon entropy, treating the comparisons as weighing in the classic "find the heavy/light ball" problem would be a good way to approach this. Calculating the Shannon entropy of any configuration should be linear, so this approach would theoretically be nlogn. I'm at work now though, if this is still open in a few hours I'll try massaging this into a real answer.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I don't think this is getting any close votes anytime soon.

Comment: @JanDvorak, the situation with dependencies is best illustrated with another example: `#include <netinet/igmp.h>` on just about anything other than GNU libc, without having done `#include <sys/types.h>` and/or `#include <netinet/in.h>` first.  The oracle gives back only one bit: "there was an error" or not.  (Which is to say, I don't want to try to parse the error messages.)  And yes, the list of dependencies are known in advance.

Comment: It is easy to come up with three header files that cannot be included together, but can be included pairwise.

Comment: @n.m. I can *write* three such headers, but I'm not aware of any OS where three such headers *exist in `/usr/include`*.  That said, it certainly would be nice if the algorithm could handle that case.

Comment: The fact that you have an arbitrary set of one-direction known conflicts, or dependencies as you call them, is probably going to make it very hard to quickly find all new conflicts if the set of dependencies is large and/or the dependencies involve a large number of your items

Comment: In terms of asymptotics, unless you have an asymptotic bound on the total number of conflicts, or some other property to work with, there's no getting away from worst-case O(n^2) time -- since it could be that every object conflicts with every other object, and there's no way to determine this without testing every pair.

Comment: @j_random_hacker This is true, and there's no *theoretical* limit; however, in practice there are many fewer conflicts than objects.  (Typical numbers: 200 headers, less than ten conflicts.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker I merged all three answers to this question into something that works acceptably well in practice.  If you are curious, <https://github.com/zackw/header-survey/blob/master/survey-scan> is the program that needs this algorithm, and the part dealing specifically with conflict detection starts at [line 3272](https://github.com/zackw/header-survey/blob/master/survey-scan#L3272).  The overall project is incomplete because I ran out of time, let me know if you're interested in helping.

Comment: It would be cool to work on this (very cute!) topic, but alas I also have other (less interesting) things that need doing...  In any case, conceptually, any possible solution is a *decision tree* with a test at each node, and 2 children, which represent the next test to perform for each of the possible outcomes; a node is a leaf if all n(n-1) answers are known by then.  Minimising the worst-case number of oracle calls == minimising the height of this tree -- but as I said, that could be O(n^2), and would still be hard even if we assume a bound on the number of conflicts.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I'm not sure asymptotic analysis is the right way to look at this problem.  N is small and effectively fixed (every five years or so maybe ISO or POSIX add a few more headers and it goes up a little), and the thing that must be minimized at all costs is the total number of compiler invocations.  If a brute-force SAT solver could reduce the number of compiler invocations somehow, *it might well be faster overall*. (Not that I would want to wire any sort of SAT solver into this Python 2.0-compatible program!)

Comment: Well, I think an asymptotic bound in terms of some measure of the *output* size (number of conflicts, or number of objects involved in a conflict), as user2566092 looks for, would be nice...  But I don't know an obvious way to do that either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few suggestions:

### Finding a single conflict

Suppose that you know there is a conflict in n items, you can use O(log n) operations to find the location of a single conflict by first bisecting on the end point, and then bisecting on the start point.

For example, this might look like:

```
Test 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 -> Conflict
Test 1,2,3,4,5 -> Good
Test 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 -> Conflict
Test 1,2,3,4,5,6 -> Good (Now deduce Endpoint is 7, the last end with a conflict)
Test 3,4,5,6 -> Conflict
Test 5,6 -> Good
Test 4,5,6 -> Conflict (Now deduce Startpoint is 4.)
```

You now know that 4,5,6,7 is tight (i.e. cannot be made any smaller without removing a conflict), so we can deduce that 4 and 7 must conflict.

### Finding more conflicts

Once you have found a problem, you can remove one of the offending items, and test the remaining set.  If this still conflicts, you can use the bisection method to identify another conflict.

Repeat until no more conflicts are found.

### Finding remaining conflicts

You should now have a large set of not conflicting items, and a few items that have been removed which may have additional conflicts.

To find remaining conflicts you might want to try taking one of the removed items, and then reinserting all items (except those that we already know conflict with it).  This should either identify another conflict, or prove that all conflicts with that item have been found.

You can repeat this process with each of the removed items to find all remaining conflicts.

Comment: The thing I eventually ended up doing has elements of all three answers but is most similar to this, so you get the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find answers for n*(n-1) questions, each question being if an ordered pair has a conflict. Whenever you send a sequence of length k and the oracle says "good", you will have answers to k(k-1) such questions.

Create and initialize these n*(n-1) questions as a adjacency matrix with default values -1 (set self-edges as 0). Permute the sequence randomly and apply your recursive algorithm. Whenever you find that a sequence has no conflict mark the corresponding answer in the matrix (0). Mark as conflict (1) if a sequence of exactly two has a conflict.

Now, after on big iteration you have this matrix with -1s, 0s and 1s. Assume -1s are the edges and find the longest path. Reapply your algorithm. Keep doing this until number of unknowns is very small. At which point you send out pairs to the oracle.

Comment: I regret to say this answer tells me how to do the part I already knew how to do.  It's the "recursive algorithm" that's got a hole in it.

Comment: @Zack You cannot fill that hole IMHO. Basically, if there is a conflict it tells you little about the divided subsets. The best you can do is to **bet** that a sequence does not have any conflicts and you can quantify the wins and losses due to that bet. I am suggesting a systematic way (i.e. to tabulate your knowledge and represent your partial solution using a graph).

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you have hundreds of headers and less than 10 conflicts, I am going to give a worst-case optimal solution under the assumption that you have n items and O(lg n) items involved in conflicts.  In the worst-case, if you have Theta(lg n) items involved in conflicts, then all of these items conflict with each other and there is no way to determine this using fewer than Omega((lg n)^2) oracle calls.  Thus O((lg n)^2) oracle calls would be optimal, assuming Theta(lg n) items involved in conflicts.

Anyway here'e the algorithm.  First you do like another answer said, and iteratively identify a conflict in O(lg n) oracle calls and remove one item in the conflict from your set, until you are left with a set that has no conflicts.  This takes at most O((lg n)^2) oracle calls.  Then for each item Z you removed, you put Z at the beginning of the no-conflict set, and perform binary search to find a later item X that creates a conflict, or determine that none exists.  (And if such X is found, remove X and repeat).  Thus you find all conflicts that begin with Z, and each such conflict is found in O(lg n) oracle calls.  Similarly you put Z at the end of the no-conflict list and perform binary search to find all preceding elements X that create a conflict.  Then, the only thing left to do is find all conflicts among the items you originally removed in the first step of the algorithm.  But there are only O(lg n) of them by assumption, so this takes O((lg n)^2) oracle calls.  The overall number of oracle calls is thus O((lg n)^2).

Comment: Note this is not necessarily output-sensitive optiomal, in the sense that you may have Theta(lg n) conflicts if you have Theta(lg n) items involved in conflicts, while Theta((lg n)^2) oracle calls would still be used.  I'd be interested to see if someone can assume, say, O(lg n) CONFLICTS instead of items involved in conflicts, and come up with an algorithm that beats the O((lg n)^2) oracle calls presented here

Comment: It seems to me that O((lg n)^3) oracle calls may be needed.  Suppose that in the first step (namely, producing a no-conflict list), k = O(lg n) items are identified and removed (in O((lg n)^2) time as you say).  I think it can be that the no-conflict list contains a *different* set of k items, each of which conflicts with *all* of the k items just removed.  (This would mean that 2k items are involved in conflicts -- but that's still O((lg n)^2).) ...

Comment: ... Now, each Z tried in step 2 produces k conflicts in O(k^2) time -- but there are k removed items to try, so O(k^3) = O((lg n)^3) time is needed overall to find the O((lg n)^2) conflicts.